# Error Connecting To (MAMP Pro) Database in Console Command

Tags: plugin-development

i know this might be a bit out of bounds for this stackexchange site, but i am going a bit batty and any help would be amazing

i am trying to get a console plugin up and running. i started with just the shell of one. got all the basics in place. then when i run `craft/app/etc/console/yiic.php` (with no params) to get a list of available commands, i get db connection errors.

things to note:

- i can run `yiic.php` on my staging server (a centos LAMP cloud server instance at Rackspace) and it's fine, it just has problems locally
- i am using MAMP Pro locally
- i can load the site fine through my browser, so credentials in `config\db.php` are AOK
- i can fire up mysql from the cmdline using the same db credentials, and it's fine

any help would be so appreciated!

the dumped errors i get are as follows:

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (829)
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/console/ConsoleApp.php (203)
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (80)
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (842)
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/console/ConsoleApp.php (203)
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (80)
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (829)
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/console/ConsoleApp.php (203)
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (80)
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (842)
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/console/ConsoleApp.php (203)
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (80)
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (829)
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/console/ConsoleApp.php (203)
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (80)
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (842)
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/console/ConsoleApp.php (203)
in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (80)
exception 'CException' with message 'Craft\ConsoleApp and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getTranslatedBrowserLanguage".' in /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php:266
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php(910): CComponent->__call('getTranslatedBr...', Array)
#1 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php(910): Craft\ConsoleApp->getTranslatedBrowserLanguage()
#2 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php(800): Craft\AppBehavior->_getFallbackLanguage()
#3 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php(570): Craft\AppBehavior->getTargetLanguage(false)
#4 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/console/ConsoleApp.php(103): Craft\AppBehavior->getLanguage()
#5 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/framework/i18n/CMessageSource.php(83): Craft\ConsoleApp->getLanguage()
#6 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/framework/YiiBase.php(590): CMessageSource->translate('craft', 'Craft can\xE2\x80\x99t c...', NULL)
#7 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/Craft.php(382): YiiBase::t('craft', 'Craft can\xE2\x80\x99t c...', Array, NULL, NULL)
#8 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php(843): Craft\Craft::t('Craft can\xE2\x80\x99t c...')
#9 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/console/ConsoleApp.php(203): Craft\AppBehavior->createDbConnection()
#10 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php(80): Craft\ConsoleApp->getComponent('db')
#11 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php(487): Craft\AppBehavior->isInstalled()
#12 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php(187): Craft\AppBehavior->getInfo('edition')
#13 [internal function]: Craft\AppBehavior->getEdition()
#14 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php(261): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/console/ConsoleApp.php(307): CComponent->__call('getEdition', Array)
#16 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/console/ConsoleApp.php(307): Craft\ConsoleApp->getEdition()
#17 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/console/ConsoleApp.php(74): Craft\ConsoleApp->_setEditionComponents()
#18 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(169): Craft\ConsoleApp->init()
#19 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/framework/YiiBase.php(121): CApplication->__construct('/Users/bhu/drop...')
#20 /Users/bhu/dropbox-bhu/Dropbox/devel/binarybhu/websites/blackstarcoffee/blackstarcoffee.dev/craft/app/etc/console/yiic.php(78): YiiBase::createApplication('Craft\\ConsoleAp...', '/Users/bhu/drop...')
#21 {main}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally worked it out! when connecting through `localhost` PDO does a socket-based connection to mysql, not tcp. under MAMP the socket file is "non-standard", and so i have to set it explicitly. when running a console command via yiic.php, `CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT` is set to `console`, and so i add the following to the end of `craft/config/db.php`:

```
'console' => [
    'unixSocket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
],
```

and all is well.

#### UPDATE: Better Solution

the above is not optimal as obviously one can run a plugin from the console on a live or staging server, as well as a dev machine! so i came up with a better approach: add support for a `--mamp` cmdline parameter. so my db.php became:

```
$db_config = [

    '*' => [
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => '...',
        'password' => '...',
        'database' => '...',
        'tablePrefix' => 'craft',
    ],

];

// watch for MAMP (need to specify socket file explicitly)
if (php_sapi_name() == "cli") {
    $idx = 0;
    foreach($_SERVER['argv'] as $key => $arg) {
        if (strcasecmp($arg, '--mamp') === 0) {
            $db_config['*']['unixSocket'] = '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock';
            array_splice($_SERVER['argv'], $idx, 1);
            break;
        }
        $idx++;
    }
}


return $db_config;
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks. For my own future reference as well as others, my full command line was then `./yiic migrate create MyDataBaseUpdate MyPlugin --mamp`

Comment: Feel free to mark your own answer as correct! Certainly worked for me :)

Comment: Any luck with this in Craft 3?