# Plugin - Possible path problem in MAMP - Could not find the task component type

Tags: yiic

I have a Craft plugin that works fine on a live site and on Macs. I have recently installed MAMP (Windows) on my development machine and now, when I try to run one of the plugins commands by using GIT to CD to the Yiic console ... /c/mamp/htdocs/websitename/craft/app/etc/console ... and run the command ... php yiic pluginname commandname ... I get the error message ... Encountered an error running task 700 (plugin_task): Could not find the task component type.

I am pretty sure that the problem is that the task file is not being found, but I think I have the upper/lower case elements correct:

\pluginname\consolecommands\PluginnameCommand.php

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class PluginnameCommand extends BaseCommand
{
  public function actionUpdate($testError = false)
  {
      $task = craft()->tasks->createTask('pluginname_event', 'Updating data', [
            'testError' => $testError,
      ]);
      craft()->tasks->runTask($task);
  }
}
```

\pluginname\tasks\Pluginname_EventTask.php

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class Pluginname_EventTask extends BaseTask
{
}
```

Have I the cases wrong, or am I missing something in setup?

Note that this is a followup to ... [Running console (yiic) under MAMP (Windows)](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/21010/running-console-yiic-under-mamp-windows) ... which was a path problem solved by modifying the yiic file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is it's a case sensitivity issue between your plugin class names and the names of those files on the file system.

If you're on an NTFS filesystem on Windows, it is case sensitive.  I recommend generating boilerplate plugin code from something like https://pluginfactory.io/ (they even have a tasks checkbox) to help avoid issues like this.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That, together with some tweeks to the cases used in the function calls in the code, allowed me to get get it working.

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind marking it as an accepted answer?